# Opening media file with button press

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have one button on my wpf called '`Open Media`' with click event and a `MediaElement` to play media.
I want to open a media file by pressing that button.

It's giving me run time exception '`System.NotSupportedException`' on line '`mePlayer.Play()`'. How to achieve this using following code:

```
    private void OpenMediaButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openMedia = new OpenFileDialog();
        openMedia.Title = "Open Media";
        openMedia.Filter = "mp4 files(*.mp4)|*.mp4";
        openMedia.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openMedia.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openMedia.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            mePlayer.Source = new Uri(openMedia.FileName);
            mePlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            mePlayer.Play();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I've just run your sample and can't duplicate your problem. Have you stepped through and confirmed the value of mePlayer.Source at runtime? Is it a valid Uri? Have you tested that the file plays happily in an external player?

Comment: Thanks for reply goobering. I found the problem. 'LoadedBehavior' was set to 'Pause' instead of 'Manual'. But i didn't understand why setting it to 'Pause' generated that exception.